# How to locate bug from clients view for a syntaxerror

Tags: javascript, syntax, error-handling, cross-browser

I have webpage that uses various libraries and some personal javascript code. I've tested it on my machine and it works.

When I pushed it to production a user informed my that the page was broken. After looking at their console log I see that my page is now throwing a syntaxerror on a generic function that seems to be fine. I can't reproduce it on my machine but it happens on theirs.

I'm assuming its either a different os issue or a x-browser version issue (I'm using Win-8, Chrome they are using Mac, Chrome). I could see how a function would break and it would spit out an error saying it couldn't execute function of undefined. What would be my next step in trying to identify what could be the cause?

The syntaxerror is "Unexpected token ("

Is there some php I can inject into the page to get more info about this error?

```
var objBillManager = {
...
    objBillTableManager:{
...
        GetsBillsStatus(bPayed){
            if(bPayed == "1"){
                return "Payed";
            } else {
                return "Not Payed";
            }
        },
...
    },
...
}
```

Comment: Can you include that generic function? Without some code it's pretty hard to find a solution

Comment: Youl will have to use a browser debugging tool, `F12 or `debugger in your Jscript

Comment: I can't reproduce it in my browser and when I ask her to open her console I see Uncaught subscriptions.php:2415 (the function start above) SyntaxError: Unexpected toke (

Comment: Probably parser expects an identifier, `GetsBillsStatus(bPayed)` is not an identifier. Should be `GetsBillsStatus: function (bPayed){...}`?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more, it's hard to know what's going on. As someone else mentioned, firebug is a pretty good debugger.

One thing I noticed: your `GetsBillsStatus` was not defined as a function. It should look like this:

```
GetsBillsStatus: function(bPayed){
    if(bPayed == "1") {
        return "Payed";
    } else {
        return "Not Payed";
    }
}
```

Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll implement it and see if that fixes the issue.